# pretty-print css one-liner

Tags: text-formatting

I (human) would like to read this ~30000 chars long line of CSS.

```css
@font-face{font-family:KaTeX_Script;src:url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Script-Regular.af7bc98.woff2) format("woff2"),url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Script-Regular.4edf4e0.woff) format("woff"),url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Script-Regular.082640c.ttf) format("truetype");font-weight:400;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:KaTeX_Size1;src:url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size1-Regular.10ec8be.woff2) format("woff2"),url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size1-Regular.35b9977.woff) format("woff"),url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size1-Regular.2c2dc3b.ttf) format("truetype");font-weight:400;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:KaTeX_Size2;src:url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size2-Regular.96a09bf.woff2) format("woff2"),url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size2-Regular.9932a08.woff) format("woff"),url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size2-Regular.114ad19.ttf) format("truetype");font-weight:400;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:KaTeX_Size3;src:url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size3-Regular.2c2f0ef.woff2) format("woff2"),url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size3-Regular.2afba15.woff) format("woff"),url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size3-Regular.a287c06.ttf) format("truetype");font-weight:400;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:KaTeX_Size4;src:url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size4-Regular.d5822f1.woff2) format("woff2"),url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size4-Regular.f961545.woff) format("woff"),url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size4-Regular.70174da.ttf) format("truetype");font-weight:400;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:KaTeX_Typewriter;src:url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Typewriter-Regular.641339e.woff2) format("woff2"),url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Typewriter-Regular.53dcf86.woff) format("woff"),url(/static/fonts/KaTeX_Typewriter-Regular.35fe2cc.ttf) format("truetype");font-weight:400;font-style:normal}.katex{font:normal 1.21em KaTeX_Main,Times New Roman,serif;line-height:1.2;text-indent:0;text-rendering:auto;border-color:currentColor}.katex *{-ms-high-contrast-adjust:none!important}.katex .katex-version:after{content:"0.13.0"}.katex .katex-mathml{position:absolute;clip:rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);padding:0;border:0;height:1px;width:1px;overflow:hidden}.katex .katex-html>.newline{display:block}.katex .base{position:relative;white-space:nowrap;width:-webkit-min-content;width:-moz-min-content;width:min-content}.katex .base,.katex .strut{display:inline-block}.katex .textbf{font-weight:700}.katex .textit{font-style:italic}.katex .textrm{font-family:KaTeX_Main}.katex .textsf{font-family:KaTeX_SansSerif}.katex .texttt{font-family:KaTeX_Typewriter}.katex .mathnormal{font-family:KaTeX_Math;font-style:italic}.katex .mathit{font-family:KaTeX_Main;font-style:italic}.katex .mathrm{font-style:normal}.katex .mathbf{font-family:KaTeX_Main;font-weight:700}.katex .boldsymbol{font-family:KaTeX_Math;font-weight:700;font-style:italic}.katex .amsrm,.katex .mathbb,.katex .textbb{font-family:KaTeX_AMS}.katex .mathcal{font-family:KaTeX_Caligraphic}.katex .mathfrak,.katex .textfrak{font-family:KaTeX_Fraktur}.katex .mathtt{font-family:KaTeX_Typewriter}.katex .mathscr,.katex .textscr{font-family:KaTeX_Script}.katex .mathsf,.katex .textsf{font-family:KaTeX_SansSerif}.katex .mathboldsf,.katex .textboldsf{font-family:KaTeX_SansSerif;font-weight:700}.katex .mathitsf,.katex .textitsf{font-family:KaTeX_SansSerif;font-style:italic}.katex .mainrm{font-family:KaTeX_Main;font-style:normal}.katex .vlist-t{display:inline-table;table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse}.katex .vlist-r{display:table-row}.katex .vlist{display:table-cell;vertical-align:bottom;position:relative}.katex .vlist>span{display:block;height:0;position:relative}.katex .vlist>span>span{display:inline-block}.katex .vlist>span>.pstrut{overflow:hidden;width:0}.katex .vlist-t2{margin-right:-2px}.katex .vlist-s{display:table-cell;vertical-align:bottom;font-size:1px;width:2px;min-width:2px}.katex .vbox{display:inline-flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:baseline}.katex .hbox{width:100%}.katex .hbox,.katex .thinbox{display:inline-flex;flex-direction:row}.katex .thinbox{width:0;max-width:0}.katex .msupsub{text-align:left}.katex .mfrac>span>span{text-align:center}.katex .mfrac .frac-line{display:inline-block;width:100%;border-bottom-style:solid}.katex .hdashline,.katex .hline,.katex .mfrac .frac-line,.katex .overline .overline-line,.katex .rule,.katex .underline .underline-line{min-height:1px}.katex .mspace{display:inline-block}.katex .clap,.katex .llap,.katex .rlap{width:0;position:relative}.katex .clap>.inner,.katex .llap>.inner,.katex .rlap>.inner{position:absolute}.katex .clap>.fix,.katex .llap>.fix,.katex .rlap>.fix{display:inline-block}.katex .llap>.inner{right:0}.katex .clap>.inner,.katex .rlap>.inner{left:0}.katex .clap>.inner>span{margin-left:-50%;margin-right:50%}.katex .rule{display:inline-block;border:0 solid;position:relative}.katex .hline,.katex .overline .overline-line,.katex .underline .underline-line{display:inline-block;width:100%;border-bottom-style:solid}.katex .hdashline{display:inline-block;width:100%;border-bottom-style:dashed}.katex .sqrt>.root{margin-left:.27777778em;margin-right:-.55555556em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size1,.katex .sizing.reset-size1.size1{font-size:1em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size2,.katex .sizing.reset-size1.size2{font-size:1.2em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size3,.katex .sizing.reset-size1.size3{font-size:1.4em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size4,.katex .sizing.reset-size1.size4{font-size:1.6em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size5,.katex .sizing.reset-size1.size5{font-size:1.8em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size6,.katex .sizing.reset-size1.size6{font-size:2em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size7,.katex .sizing.reset-size1.size7{font-size:2.4em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size8,.katex .sizing.reset-size1.size8{font-size:2.88em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size9,.katex .sizing.reset-size1.size9{font-size:3.456em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size10,.katex .sizing.reset-size1.size10{font-size:4.148em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size11,.katex .sizing.reset-size1.size11{font-size:4.976em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size1,.katex .sizing.reset-size2.size1{font-size:.83333333em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size2,.katex .sizing.reset-size2.size2{font-size:1em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size3,.katex .sizing.reset-size2.size3{font-size:1.16666667em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size4,.katex .sizing.reset-size2.size4{font-size:1.33333333em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size5,.katex .sizing.reset-size2.size5{font-size:1.5em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size6,.katex .sizing.reset-size2.size6{font-size:1.66666667em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size7,.katex .sizing.reset-size2.size7{font-size:2em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size8,.katex .sizing.reset-size2.size8{font-size:2.4em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size9,.katex .sizing.reset-size2.size9{font-size:2.88em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size10,.katex .sizing.reset-size2.size10{font-size:3.45666667em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size11,.katex .sizing.reset-size2.size11{font-size:4.14666667em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size1,.katex .sizing.reset-size3.size1{font-size:.71428571em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size2,.katex .sizing.reset-size3.size2{font-size:.85714286em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size3,.katex .sizing.reset-size3.size3{font-size:1em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size4,.katex .sizing.reset-size3.size4{font-size:1.14285714em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size5,.katex .sizing.reset-size3.size5{font-size:1.28571429em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size6,.katex .sizing.reset-size3.size6{font-size:1.42857143em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size7,.katex .sizing.reset-size3.size7{font-size:1.71428571em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size8,.katex .sizing.reset-size3.size8{font-size:2.05714286em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size9,.katex .sizing.reset-size3.size9{font-size:2.46857143em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size10,.katex .sizing.reset-size3.size10{font-size:2.96285714em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size11,.katex .sizing.reset-size3.size11{font-size:3.55428571em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size1,.katex .sizing.reset-size4.size1{font-size:.625em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size2,.katex .sizing.reset-size4.size2{font-size:.75em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size3,.katex .sizing.reset-size4.size3{font-size:.875em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size4,.katex .sizing.reset-size4.size4{font-size:1em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size5,.katex .sizing.reset-size4.size5{font-size:1.125em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size6,.katex .sizing.reset-size4.size6{font-size:1.25em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size7,.katex .sizing.reset-size4.size7{font-size:1.5em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size8,.katex .sizing.reset-size4.size8{font-size:1.8em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size9,.katex .sizing.reset-size4.size9{font-size:2.16em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size10,.katex .sizing.reset-size4.size10{font-size:2.5925em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size11,.katex .sizing.reset-size4.size11{font-size:3.11em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size1,.katex .sizing.reset-size5.size1{font-size:.55555556em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size2,.katex .sizing.reset-size5.size2{font-size:.66666667em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size3,.katex .sizing.reset-size5.size3{font-size:.77777778em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size4,.katex .sizing.reset-size5.size4{font-size:.88888889em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size5,.katex .sizing.reset-size5.size5{font-size:1em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size6,.katex .sizing.reset-size5.size6{font-size:1.11111111em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size7,.katex .sizing.reset-size5.size7{font-size:1.33333333em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size8,.katex .sizing.reset-size5.size8{font-size:1.6em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size9,.katex .sizing.reset-size5.size9{font-size:1.92em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size10,.katex .sizing.reset-size5.size10{font-size:2.30444444em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size11,.katex .sizing.reset-size5.size11{font-size:2.76444444em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size1,.katex .sizing.reset-size6.size1{font-size:.5em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size2,.katex .sizing.reset-size6.size2{font-size:.6em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size3,.katex .sizing.reset-size6.size3{font-size:.7em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size4,.katex .sizing.reset-size6.size4{font-size:.8em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size5,.katex .sizing.reset-size6.size5{font-size:.9em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size6,.katex .sizing.reset-size6.size6{font-size:1em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size7,.katex .sizing.reset-size6.size7{font-size:1.2em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size8,.katex .sizing.reset-size6.size8{font-size:1.44em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size9,.katex .sizing.reset-size6.size9{font-size:1.728em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size10,.katex .sizing.reset-size6.size10{font-size:2.074em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size11,.katex .sizing.reset-size6.size11{font-size:2.488em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size1,.katex .sizing.reset-size7.size1{font-size:.41666667em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size2,.katex .sizing.reset-size7.size2{font-size:.5em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size3,.katex .sizing.reset-size7.size3{font-size:.58333333em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size4,.katex .sizing.reset-size7.size4{font-size:.66666667em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size5,.katex .sizing.reset-size7.size5{font-size:.75em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size6,.katex .sizing.reset-size7.size6{font-size:.83333333em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size7,.katex .sizing.reset-size7.size7{font-size:1em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size8,.katex .sizing.reset-size7.size8{font-size:1.2em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size9,.katex .sizing.reset-size7.size9{font-size:1.44em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size10,.katex .sizing.reset-size7.size10{font-size:1.72833333em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size11,.katex .sizing.reset-size7.size11{font-size:2.07333333em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size1,.katex .sizing.reset-size8.size1{font-size:.34722222em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size2,.katex .sizing.reset-size8.size2{font-size:.41666667em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size3,.katex .sizing.reset-size8.size3{font-size:.48611111em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size4,.katex .sizing.reset-size8.size4{font-size:.55555556em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size5,.katex .sizing.reset-size8.size5{font-size:.625em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size6,.katex .sizing.reset-size8.size6{font-size:.69444444em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size7,.katex .sizing.reset-size8.size7{font-size:.83333333em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size8,.katex .sizing.reset-size8.size8{font-size:1em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size9,.katex .sizing.reset-size8.size9{font-size:1.2em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size10,.katex .sizing.reset-size8.size10{font-size:1.44027778em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size11,.katex .sizing.reset-size8.size11{font-size:1.72777778em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size1,.katex .sizing.reset-size9.size1{font-size:.28935185em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size2,.katex .sizing.reset-size9.size2{font-size:.34722222em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size3,.katex .sizing.reset-size9.size3{font-size:.40509259em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size4,.katex .sizing.reset-size9.size4{font-size:.46296296em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size5,.katex .sizing.reset-size9.size5{font-size:.52083333em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size6,.katex .sizing.reset-size9.size6{font-size:.5787037em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size7,.katex .sizing.reset-size9.size7{font-size:.69444444em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size8,.katex .sizing.reset-size9.size8{font-size:.83333333em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size9,.katex .sizing.reset-size9.size9{font-size:1em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size10,.katex .sizing.reset-size9.size10{font-size:1.20023148em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size11,.katex .sizing.reset-size9.size11{font-size:1.43981481em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size1,.katex .sizing.reset-size10.size1{font-size:.24108004em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size2,.katex .sizing.reset-size10.size2{font-size:.28929605em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size3,.katex .sizing.reset-size10.size3{font-size:.33751205em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size4,.katex .sizing.reset-size10.size4{font-size:.38572806em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size5,.katex .sizing.reset-size10.size5{font-size:.43394407em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size6,.katex .sizing.reset-size10.size6{font-size:.48216008em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size7,.katex .sizing.reset-size10.size7{font-size:.57859209em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size8,.katex .sizing.reset-size10.size8{font-size:.69431051em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size9,.katex .sizing.reset-size10.size9{font-size:.83317261em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size10,.katex .sizing.reset-size10.size10{font-size:1em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size11,.katex .sizing.reset-size10.size11{font-size:1.19961427em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size1,.katex .sizing.reset-size11.size1{font-size:.20096463em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size2,.katex .sizing.reset-size11.size2{font-size:.24115756em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size3,.katex .sizing.reset-size11.size3{font-size:.28135048em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size4,.katex .sizing.reset-size11.size4{font-size:.32154341em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size5,.katex .sizing.reset-size11.size5{font-size:.36173633em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size6,.katex .sizing.reset-size11.size6{font-size:.40192926em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size7,.katex .sizing.reset-size11.size7{font-size:.48231511em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size8,.katex .sizing.reset-size11.size8{font-size:.57877814em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size9,.katex .sizing.reset-size11.size9{font-size:.69453376em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size10,.katex .sizing.reset-size11.size10{font-size:.83360129em}.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size11,.katex .sizing.reset-size11.size11{font-size:1em}.katex .delimsizing.size1{font-family:KaTeX_Size1}.katex .delimsizing.size2{font-family:KaTeX_Size2}.katex .delimsizing.size3{font-family:KaTeX_Size3}.katex .delimsizing.size4{font-family:KaTeX_Size4}.katex .delimsizing.mult .delim-size1>span{font-family:KaTeX_Size1}.katex .delimsizing.mult .delim-size4>span{font-family:KaTeX_Size4}.katex .nulldelimiter{display:inline-block;width:.12em}.katex .delimcenter,.katex .op-symbol{position:relative}.katex .op-symbol.small-op{font-family:KaTeX_Size1}.katex .op-symbol.large-op{font-family:KaTeX_Size2}.katex .accent>.vlist-t,.katex .op-limits>.vlist-t{text-align:center}.katex .accent .accent-body{position:relative}.katex .accent .accent-body:not(.accent-full){width:0}.katex .overlay{display:block}.katex .mtable .vertical-separator{display:inline-block;min-width:1px}.katex .mtable .arraycolsep{display:inline-block}.katex .mtable .col-align-c>.vlist-t{text-align:center}.katex .mtable .col-align-l>.vlist-t{text-align:left}.katex .mtable .col-align-r>.vlist-t{text-align:right}.katex .svg-align{text-align:left}.katex svg{display:block;position:absolute;width:100%;height:inherit;fill:currentColor;stroke:currentColor;fill-rule:nonzero;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1}.katex svg path{stroke:none}.katex img{border-style:none;min-width:0;min-height:0;max-width:none;max-height:none}.katex .stretchy{width:100%;display:block;position:relative;overflow:hidden}.katex .stretchy:after,.katex .stretchy:before{content:""}.katex .hide-tail{width:100%;position:relative;overflow:hidden}.katex .halfarrow-left{position:absolute;left:0;width:50.2%;overflow:hidden}.katex .halfarrow-right{position:absolute;right:0;width:50.2%;overflow:hidden}.katex .brace-left{position:absolute;left:0;width:25.1%;overflow:hidden}.katex .brace-center{position:absolute;left:25%;width:50%;overflow:hidden}.katex .brace-right{position:absolute;right:0;width:25.1%;overflow:hidden}.katex .x-arrow-pad{padding:0 .5em}.katex .cd-arrow-pad{padding:0 .55556em 0 .27778em}.katex .mover,.katex .munder,.katex .x-arrow{text-align:center}.katex .boxpad{padding:0 .3em}.katex .fbox,.katex .fcolorbox{box-sizing:border-box;border:.04em solid}.katex .cancel-pad{padding:0 .2em}.katex .cancel-lap{margin-left:-.2em;margin-right:-.2em}.katex .sout{border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:.08em}.katex .angl{box-sizing:border-content;border-top:.049em solid;border-right:.049em solid;margin-right:.03889em}.katex .anglpad{padding:0 .03889em}.katex .eqn-num:before{counter-increment:a;content:"(" counter(a) ")"}.katex .mml-eqn-num:before{counter-increment:b;content:"(" counter(b) ")"}.katex .mtr-glue{width:50%}.katex .cd-vert-arrow{display:inline-block;position:relative}.katex .cd-label-left{display:inline-block;position:absolute;right:calc(50% + .3em);text-align:left}.katex .cd-label-right{display:inline-block;position:absolute;left:calc(50% + .3em);text-align:right}.katex-display{display:block;margin:1em 0;text-align:center}.katex-display>.katex{display:block;text-align:center;white-space:nowrap}.katex-display>.katex>.katex-html{display:block;position:relative}.katex-display>.katex>.katex-html>.tag{position:absolute;right:0}.katex-display.leqno>.katex>.katex-html>.tag{left:0;right:auto}.katex-display.fleqn>.katex{text-align:left;padding-left:2em}body{counter-reset:a b}@font-face{font-family:Lato;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(/static/fonts/lato-normal.27bd77b.woff) format("woff")}@font-face{font-family:Lato;font-style:italic;font-weight:400;src:url(/static/fonts/lato-normal-italic.f28f2d6.woff) format("woff")}@font-face{font-family:Lato;font-style:normal;font-weight:600;src:url(/static/fonts/lato-black.f80bda6.woff) format("woff")}@font-face{font-family:Lato;font-style:italic;font-weight:600;src:url(/static/fonts/lato-black-italic.798eafd.woff) format("woff")}@font-face{font-family:Roboto Mono;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(/static/fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.0b6a547.woff) format("woff")}@font-face{font-family:Roboto Mono;font-style:normal;font-weight:600;src:url(/static/fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.819f3b2.woff) format("woff")}.prism *,.token.pre.gfm *{font-weight:inherit!important}.prism .token.cdata,.prism .token.comment,.prism .token.doctype,.prism .token.prolog,.token.pre.gfm .token.cdata,.token.pre.gfm .token.comment,.token.pre.gfm .token.doctype,.token.pre.gfm .token.prolog{color:#708090}.prism .token.punctuation,.token.pre.gfm .token.punctuation{color:#999}.prism .namespace,.token.pre.gfm .namespace{opacity:.7}.prism .token.boolean,.prism .token.constant,.prism .token.deleted,.prism .token.number,.prism .token.property,.prism .token.symbol,.prism .token.tag,.token.pre.gfm .token.boolean,.token.pre.gfm .token.constant,.token.pre.gfm .token.deleted,.token.pre.gfm .token.number,.token.pre.gfm .token.property,.token.pre.gfm .token.symbol,.token.pre.gfm .token.tag{color:#905}.prism .token.attr-name,.prism .token.builtin,.prism .token.char,.prism .token.inserted,.prism .token.selector,.prism .token.string,.token.pre.gfm .token.attr-name,.token.pre.gfm .token.builtin,.token.pre.gfm .token.char,.token.pre.gfm .token.inserted,.token.pre.gfm .token.selector,.token.pre.gfm .token.string{color:#690}.prism .language-css .token.string,.prism .style .token.string,.prism .token.entity,.prism .token.operator,.prism .token.url,.token.pre.gfm .language-css .token.string,.token.pre.gfm .style .token.string,.token.pre.gfm .token.entity,.token.pre.gfm .token.operator,.token.pre.gfm .token.url{color:#a67f59}.prism .token.atrule,.prism .token.attr-value,.prism .token.keyword,.token.pre.gfm .token.atrule,.token.pre.gfm .token.attr-value,.token.pre.gfm .token.keyword{color:#07a}.prism .token.function,.token.pre.gfm .token.function{color:#dd4a68}.prism .token.important,.prism .token.regex,.prism .token.variable,.token.pre.gfm .token.important,.token.pre.gfm .token.regex,.token.pre.gfm .token.variable{color:#e90}.prism .token.bold,.prism .token.important,.token.pre.gfm .token.bold,.token.pre.gfm .token.important{font-weight:500}.prism .token.italic,.token.pre.gfm .token.italic{font-style:italic}/*! normalize-scss | MIT/GPLv2 License | bit.ly/normalize-scss */html{line-height:1.15;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,footer,header,nav,section{display:block}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}figcaption,figure{display:block}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{box-sizing:content-box;height:0;overflow:visible}main{display:block}pre{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}a{background-color:transparent;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:objects}abbr[title]{border-bottom:none;text-decoration:underline;text-decoration:underline dotted}b,strong{font-weight:inherit;font-weight:bolder}code,kbd,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}dfn{font-style:italic}mark{background-color:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sub{bottom:-.25em}sup{top:-.5em}audio,video{display:inline-block}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}img{border-style:none}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{font-family:sans-serif;font-size:100%;line-height:1.15;margin:0}button{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}[type=reset],[type=submit],button,html [type=button]{-webkit-appearance:button}[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner,[type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner,[type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner,button::-moz-focus-inner{border-style:none;padding:0}[type=button]:-moz-focusring,[type=reset]:-moz-focusring,[type=submit]:-moz-focusring,button:-moz-focusring{outline:1px dotted ButtonText}input{overflow:visible}[type=checkbox],[type=radio]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}fieldset{padding:.35em .75em .625em}legend{box-sizing:border-box;display:table;max-width:100%;padding:0;color:inherit;white-space:normal}progress{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}textarea{overflow:auto}details{display:block}summary{display:list-item}menu{display:block}canvas{display:inline-block}[hidden],template{display:none}body,html{color:rgba(0,0,0,.75);font-size:16px;font-family:Lato,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-variant-ligatures:common-ligatures;line-height:1.67;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.app--dark .layout__panel--editor,.app--dark .layout__panel--preview{color:hsla(0,0%,100%,.75)}blockquote,dl,ol,p,pre,ul{margin:1.2em 0}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{margin:1.8em 0;line-height:1.33}h1:after,h2:after{content:"";display:block;position:relative;top:.33em;border-bottom:1px solid hsla(0,0%,50%,.33)}ol ol,ol ul,ul ol,ul ul{margin:0}dt{font-weight:700}a{color:#0c93e4;text-decoration:underline;text-decoration-skip:ink}a:focus,a:hover{text-decoration:none}code,pre,samp{font-family:Roboto Mono,Lucida Sans Typewriter,Lucida Console,monaco,Courrier,monospace;font-size:.85em}code *,pre *,samp *{font-size:inherit}blockquote{color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);padding-left:1.5em;border-left:5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1)}.app--dark .layout__panel--editor blockquote,.app--dark .layout__panel--preview blockquote{color:hsla(0,0%,100%,.4);border-left-color:hsla(0,0%,100%,.1)}code{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05);border-radius:3px;padding:2px 4px}hr{border:0;border-top:1px solid hsla(0,0%,50%,.33);margin:2em 0}pre>code{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05);display:block;padding:.5em;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;overflow-x:auto;white-space:pre}.toc ul{list-style-type:none;padding-left:20px}table{background-color:transparent;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{border-right:1px solid #dcdcdc;padding:8px 12px}td:last-child,th:last-child{border-right:0}td{border-top:1px solid #dcdcdc}mark{background-color:#f8f840}kbd{font-family:Lato,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid rgba(63,63,63,.25);border-radius:3px;box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(63,63,63,.25);color:#333;display:inline-block;font-size:.8em;margin:0 .1em;padding:.1em .6em;white-space:nowrap}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted #777;cursor:help}img{max-width:100%}.task-list-item{list-style-type:none}.task-list-item-checkbox{margin:0 .2em 0 -1.3em}.footnote{font-size:.8em;position:relative;top:-.25em;vertical-align:top}.page-break-after{page-break-after:always}.abc-notation-block{overflow-x:auto!important}.stackedit__html{margin-bottom:180px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;max-width:750px}.stackedit__toc ul{padding:0}.stackedit__toc ul a{margin:.5rem 0;padding:.5rem 1rem}.stackedit__toc ul ul{color:#888;font-size:.9em}.stackedit__toc ul ul a{margin:0;padding:.1rem 1rem}.stackedit__toc li{display:block}.stackedit__toc a{display:block;color:inherit;text-decoration:none}.stackedit__toc a:active,.stackedit__toc a:focus,.stackedit__toc a:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.075);border-radius:3px}.stackedit__left{position:fixed;display:none;width:250px;height:100%;top:0;left:0;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;-ms-overflow-style:none}@media (min-width:1060px){.stackedit__left{display:block}}.stackedit__right{position:absolute;right:0;top:0;left:0}@media (min-width:1060px){.stackedit__right{left:250px}}.stackedit--pdf blockquote{border-left-color:#ececec}.stackedit--pdf .stackedit__html{padding-left:0;padding-right:0;max-width:none}
```

Is there a common tool I could use ?

Comment: use [Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html)

Comment: Is there something in there that you expect to differ from the original stylesheet from KaTeX prior to minification?

Comment: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.4/dist/katex.css

Comment: @MarcusMüller My CSS comes from stackedit.io. Maybe there's more than the katex.css

Comment: Interesting, but when I use stackedit, type in a formula (`$$foo$$`), then in the rendered output right-click -> "Inspect", then in the style display click on the little link where it says that the katex style is from, I get a very nice multiline display. Try that!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes ! So I wonder if there's a command-line tool to get that.

Comment: that's going to be hard, as what firefox does there is download HTML, run javascript, populating the document tree, and then is able to determine which computed style applies to elements. You can,as don already said yesterday,run your CSS through Prettier, but it won't change the fact that you're just formatting some style sheet with elements that do not all apply to all the elements in a website, and get overruled by other styles, generated statically or on the fly. In other words, no matter how readable you make the CSS code, without the acute rendered state of the website, it's meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku**'s `css-tidy.raku` script:

If/when you install Raku's `CSS` module, three stand-alone scripts are installed along with it. They are: `css-gen-properties.raku`, `css-tidy.raku`, and `css-inliner.raku`. See:

https://raku.land/zef:dwarring/CSS
https://github.com/css-raku/CSS-raku

You can make the scripts executable in the usual way, or just alias them to a convenient location and run them at the command line with `~$ raku css-tidy.raku file.css`.

Sample Output:

```css
dropping unknown property: text-rendering
.katex { border:currentcolor; font:normal 1.21em/1.2 KaTeX_Main, Times\ New\ Roman, serif; text-indent:0; }
.katex .katex-version::after { content:'0.13.0'; }
.katex .katex-mathml { border:0; clip:rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); height:1px; overflow:hidden; padding:0; position:absolute; width:1px; }
.katex .katex-html > .newline { display:block; }
.katex .base { position:relative; white-space:nowrap; }
.katex .base, .katex .strut { display:inline-block; }
.katex .textbf { font-weight:700; }
.katex .textit { font-style:italic; }
.katex .textrm { font-family:KaTeX_Main; }
.katex .textsf { font-family:KaTeX_SansSerif; }
.katex .texttt { font-family:KaTeX_Typewriter; }
.katex .mathnormal { font-family:KaTeX_Math; font-style:italic; }
.katex .mathit { font-family:KaTeX_Main; font-style:italic; }
.katex .mathrm { font-style:normal; }
.katex .mathbf { font-family:KaTeX_Main; font-weight:700; }
.katex .boldsymbol { font-family:KaTeX_Math; font-style:italic; font-weight:700; }
.katex .amsrm, .katex .mathbb, .katex .textbb { font-family:KaTeX_AMS; }
.katex .mathcal { font-family:KaTeX_Caligraphic; }
.katex .mathfrak, .katex .textfrak { font-family:KaTeX_Fraktur; }
.katex .mathtt { font-family:KaTeX_Typewriter; }
.katex .mathscr, .katex .textscr { font-family:KaTeX_Script; }
.katex .mathsf, .katex .textsf { font-family:KaTeX_SansSerif; }
.katex .mathboldsf, .katex .textboldsf { font-family:KaTeX_SansSerif; font-weight:700; }
.katex .mathitsf, .katex .textitsf { font-family:KaTeX_SansSerif; font-style:italic; }
.katex .mainrm { font-family:KaTeX_Main; font-style:normal; }
.katex .vlist-t { border-collapse:collapse; display:inline-table; table-layout:fixed; }
.katex .vlist-r { display:table-row; }
.katex .vlist { display:table-cell; position:relative; vertical-align:bottom; }
.katex .vlist > span { display:block; height:0; position:relative; }
.katex .vlist > span > span { display:inline-block; }
.katex .vlist > span > .pstrut { overflow:hidden; width:0; }
.katex .vlist-t2 { margin-right:-2px; }
.katex .vlist-s { display:table-cell; font-size:1px; min-width:2px; vertical-align:bottom; width:2px; }
.katex .hbox { width:100%; }
.katex .thinbox { max-width:0; width:0; }
.katex .msupsub { text-align:left; }
.katex .mfrac > span > span { text-align:center; }
.katex .mfrac .frac-line { border-bottom:solid; display:inline-block; width:100%; }
.katex .hdashline, .katex .hline, .katex .mfrac .frac-line, .katex .overline .overline-line, .katex .rule, .katex .underline .underline-line { min-height:1px; }
.katex .mspace { display:inline-block; }
.katex .clap, .katex .llap, .katex .rlap { position:relative; width:0; }
.katex .clap > .inner, .katex .llap > .inner, .katex .rlap > .inner { position:absolute; }
.katex .clap > .fix, .katex .llap > .fix, .katex .rlap > .fix { display:inline-block; }
.katex .llap > .inner { right:0; }
.katex .clap > .inner, .katex .rlap > .inner { left:0; }
.katex .clap > .inner > span { margin-left:-50%; margin-right:50%; }
.katex .rule { border:0 solid; display:inline-block; position:relative; }
.katex .hline, .katex .overline .overline-line, .katex .underline .underline-line { border-bottom:solid; display:inline-block; width:100%; }
.katex .hdashline { border-bottom:dashed; display:inline-block; width:100%; }
.katex .sqrt > .root { margin-left:0.27777778em; margin-right:-0.55555556em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size1, .katex .sizing.reset-size1.size1 { font-size:em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size2, .katex .sizing.reset-size1.size2 { font-size:1.2em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size3, .katex .sizing.reset-size1.size3 { font-size:1.4em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size4, .katex .sizing.reset-size1.size4 { font-size:1.6em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size5, .katex .sizing.reset-size1.size5 { font-size:1.8em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size6, .katex .sizing.reset-size1.size6 { font-size:2em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size7, .katex .sizing.reset-size1.size7 { font-size:2.4em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size8, .katex .sizing.reset-size1.size8 { font-size:2.88em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size9, .katex .sizing.reset-size1.size9 { font-size:3.456em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size10, .katex .sizing.reset-size1.size10 { font-size:4.148em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size1.size11, .katex .sizing.reset-size1.size11 { font-size:4.976em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size1, .katex .sizing.reset-size2.size1 { font-size:0.83333333em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size2, .katex .sizing.reset-size2.size2 { font-size:em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size3, .katex .sizing.reset-size2.size3 { font-size:1.16666667em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size4, .katex .sizing.reset-size2.size4 { font-size:1.33333333em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size5, .katex .sizing.reset-size2.size5 { font-size:1.5em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size6, .katex .sizing.reset-size2.size6 { font-size:1.66666667em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size7, .katex .sizing.reset-size2.size7 { font-size:2em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size8, .katex .sizing.reset-size2.size8 { font-size:2.4em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size9, .katex .sizing.reset-size2.size9 { font-size:2.88em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size10, .katex .sizing.reset-size2.size10 { font-size:3.45666667em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size2.size11, .katex .sizing.reset-size2.size11 { font-size:4.14666667em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size1, .katex .sizing.reset-size3.size1 { font-size:0.71428571em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size2, .katex .sizing.reset-size3.size2 { font-size:0.85714286em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size3, .katex .sizing.reset-size3.size3 { font-size:em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size4, .katex .sizing.reset-size3.size4 { font-size:1.14285714em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size5, .katex .sizing.reset-size3.size5 { font-size:1.28571429em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size6, .katex .sizing.reset-size3.size6 { font-size:1.42857143em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size7, .katex .sizing.reset-size3.size7 { font-size:1.71428571em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size8, .katex .sizing.reset-size3.size8 { font-size:2.05714286em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size9, .katex .sizing.reset-size3.size9 { font-size:2.46857143em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size10, .katex .sizing.reset-size3.size10 { font-size:2.96285714em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size3.size11, .katex .sizing.reset-size3.size11 { font-size:3.55428571em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size1, .katex .sizing.reset-size4.size1 { font-size:0.625em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size2, .katex .sizing.reset-size4.size2 { font-size:0.75em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size3, .katex .sizing.reset-size4.size3 { font-size:0.875em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size4, .katex .sizing.reset-size4.size4 { font-size:em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size5, .katex .sizing.reset-size4.size5 { font-size:1.125em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size6, .katex .sizing.reset-size4.size6 { font-size:1.25em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size7, .katex .sizing.reset-size4.size7 { font-size:1.5em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size8, .katex .sizing.reset-size4.size8 { font-size:1.8em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size9, .katex .sizing.reset-size4.size9 { font-size:2.16em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size10, .katex .sizing.reset-size4.size10 { font-size:2.5925em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size4.size11, .katex .sizing.reset-size4.size11 { font-size:3.11em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size1, .katex .sizing.reset-size5.size1 { font-size:0.55555556em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size2, .katex .sizing.reset-size5.size2 { font-size:0.66666667em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size3, .katex .sizing.reset-size5.size3 { font-size:0.77777778em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size4, .katex .sizing.reset-size5.size4 { font-size:0.88888889em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size5, .katex .sizing.reset-size5.size5 { font-size:em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size6, .katex .sizing.reset-size5.size6 { font-size:1.11111111em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size7, .katex .sizing.reset-size5.size7 { font-size:1.33333333em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size8, .katex .sizing.reset-size5.size8 { font-size:1.6em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size9, .katex .sizing.reset-size5.size9 { font-size:1.92em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size10, .katex .sizing.reset-size5.size10 { font-size:2.30444444em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size5.size11, .katex .sizing.reset-size5.size11 { font-size:2.76444444em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size1, .katex .sizing.reset-size6.size1 { font-size:0.5em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size2, .katex .sizing.reset-size6.size2 { font-size:0.6em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size3, .katex .sizing.reset-size6.size3 { font-size:0.7em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size4, .katex .sizing.reset-size6.size4 { font-size:0.8em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size5, .katex .sizing.reset-size6.size5 { font-size:0.9em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size6, .katex .sizing.reset-size6.size6 { font-size:em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size7, .katex .sizing.reset-size6.size7 { font-size:1.2em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size8, .katex .sizing.reset-size6.size8 { font-size:1.44em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size9, .katex .sizing.reset-size6.size9 { font-size:1.728em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size10, .katex .sizing.reset-size6.size10 { font-size:2.074em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size6.size11, .katex .sizing.reset-size6.size11 { font-size:2.488em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size1, .katex .sizing.reset-size7.size1 { font-size:0.41666667em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size2, .katex .sizing.reset-size7.size2 { font-size:0.5em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size3, .katex .sizing.reset-size7.size3 { font-size:0.58333333em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size4, .katex .sizing.reset-size7.size4 { font-size:0.66666667em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size5, .katex .sizing.reset-size7.size5 { font-size:0.75em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size6, .katex .sizing.reset-size7.size6 { font-size:0.83333333em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size7, .katex .sizing.reset-size7.size7 { font-size:em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size8, .katex .sizing.reset-size7.size8 { font-size:1.2em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size9, .katex .sizing.reset-size7.size9 { font-size:1.44em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size10, .katex .sizing.reset-size7.size10 { font-size:1.72833333em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size7.size11, .katex .sizing.reset-size7.size11 { font-size:2.07333333em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size1, .katex .sizing.reset-size8.size1 { font-size:0.34722222em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size2, .katex .sizing.reset-size8.size2 { font-size:0.41666667em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size3, .katex .sizing.reset-size8.size3 { font-size:0.48611111em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size4, .katex .sizing.reset-size8.size4 { font-size:0.55555556em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size5, .katex .sizing.reset-size8.size5 { font-size:0.625em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size6, .katex .sizing.reset-size8.size6 { font-size:0.69444444em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size7, .katex .sizing.reset-size8.size7 { font-size:0.83333333em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size8, .katex .sizing.reset-size8.size8 { font-size:em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size9, .katex .sizing.reset-size8.size9 { font-size:1.2em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size10, .katex .sizing.reset-size8.size10 { font-size:1.44027778em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size8.size11, .katex .sizing.reset-size8.size11 { font-size:1.72777778em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size1, .katex .sizing.reset-size9.size1 { font-size:0.28935185em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size2, .katex .sizing.reset-size9.size2 { font-size:0.34722222em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size3, .katex .sizing.reset-size9.size3 { font-size:0.40509259em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size4, .katex .sizing.reset-size9.size4 { font-size:0.46296296em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size5, .katex .sizing.reset-size9.size5 { font-size:0.52083333em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size6, .katex .sizing.reset-size9.size6 { font-size:0.5787037em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size7, .katex .sizing.reset-size9.size7 { font-size:0.69444444em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size8, .katex .sizing.reset-size9.size8 { font-size:0.83333333em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size9, .katex .sizing.reset-size9.size9 { font-size:em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size10, .katex .sizing.reset-size9.size10 { font-size:1.20023148em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size9.size11, .katex .sizing.reset-size9.size11 { font-size:1.43981481em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size1, .katex .sizing.reset-size10.size1 { font-size:0.24108004em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size2, .katex .sizing.reset-size10.size2 { font-size:0.28929605em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size3, .katex .sizing.reset-size10.size3 { font-size:0.33751205em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size4, .katex .sizing.reset-size10.size4 { font-size:0.38572806em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size5, .katex .sizing.reset-size10.size5 { font-size:0.43394407em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size6, .katex .sizing.reset-size10.size6 { font-size:0.48216008em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size7, .katex .sizing.reset-size10.size7 { font-size:0.57859209em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size8, .katex .sizing.reset-size10.size8 { font-size:0.69431051em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size9, .katex .sizing.reset-size10.size9 { font-size:0.83317261em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size10, .katex .sizing.reset-size10.size10 { font-size:em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size10.size11, .katex .sizing.reset-size10.size11 { font-size:1.19961427em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size1, .katex .sizing.reset-size11.size1 { font-size:0.20096463em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size2, .katex .sizing.reset-size11.size2 { font-size:0.24115756em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size3, .katex .sizing.reset-size11.size3 { font-size:0.28135048em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size4, .katex .sizing.reset-size11.size4 { font-size:0.32154341em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size5, .katex .sizing.reset-size11.size5 { font-size:0.36173633em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size6, .katex .sizing.reset-size11.size6 { font-size:0.40192926em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size7, .katex .sizing.reset-size11.size7 { font-size:0.48231511em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size8, .katex .sizing.reset-size11.size8 { font-size:0.57877814em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size9, .katex .sizing.reset-size11.size9 { font-size:0.69453376em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size10, .katex .sizing.reset-size11.size10 { font-size:0.83360129em; }
.katex .fontsize-ensurer.reset-size11.size11, .katex .sizing.reset-size11.size11 { font-size:em; }
.katex .delimsizing.size1 { font-family:KaTeX_Size1; }
.katex .delimsizing.size2 { font-family:KaTeX_Size2; }
.katex .delimsizing.size3 { font-family:KaTeX_Size3; }
.katex .delimsizing.size4 { font-family:KaTeX_Size4; }
.katex .delimsizing.mult .delim-size1 > span { font-family:KaTeX_Size1; }
.katex .delimsizing.mult .delim-size4 > span { font-family:KaTeX_Size4; }
.katex .nulldelimiter { display:inline-block; width:0.12em; }
.katex .delimcenter, .katex .op-symbol { position:relative; }
.katex .op-symbol.small-op { font-family:KaTeX_Size1; }
.katex .op-symbol.large-op { font-family:KaTeX_Size2; }
.katex .accent > .vlist-t, .katex .op-limits > .vlist-t { text-align:center; }
.katex .accent .accent-body { position:relative; }
.katex .accent .accent-body:not(.accent-full) { width:0; }
.katex .overlay { display:block; }
.katex .mtable .vertical-separator { display:inline-block; min-width:1px; }
.katex .mtable .arraycolsep { display:inline-block; }
.katex .mtable .col-align-c > .vlist-t { text-align:center; }
.katex .mtable .col-align-l > .vlist-t { text-align:left; }
.katex .mtable .col-align-r > .vlist-t { text-align:right; }
.katex .svg-align { text-align:left; }
.katex svg { display:block; height:inherit; position:absolute; width:100%; }
.katex img { border:none; max-height:none; max-width:none; min-height:0; min-width:0; }
.katex .stretchy { display:block; overflow:hidden; position:relative; width:100%; }
.katex .stretchy::after, .katex .stretchy::before { content:''; }
.katex .hide-tail { overflow:hidden; position:relative; width:100%; }
.katex .halfarrow-left { left:0; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; width:50.2%; }
.katex .halfarrow-right { overflow:hidden; position:absolute; right:0; width:50.2%; }
.katex .brace-left { left:0; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; width:25.1%; }
.katex .brace-center { left:25%; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; width:50%; }
.katex .brace-right { overflow:hidden; position:absolute; right:0; width:25.1%; }
.katex .x-arrow-pad { padding:0 0.5em; }
.katex .cd-arrow-pad { padding:0 0.55556em 0 0.27778em; }
.katex .mover, .katex .munder, .katex .x-arrow { text-align:center; }
.katex .boxpad { padding:0 0.3em; }
.katex .fbox, .katex .fcolorbox { border:0.04em solid; }
.katex .cancel-pad { padding:0 0.2em; }
.katex .cancel-lap { margin-left:-0.2em; margin-right:-0.2em; }
.katex .sout { border-bottom:0.08em solid; }
.katex .angl { border-right:0.049em solid; border-top:0.049em solid; margin-right:0.03889em; }
.katex .anglpad { padding:0 0.03889em; }
.katex .eqn-num::before { content:'(' counter(a) ')'; counter-increment:a; }
.katex .mml-eqn-num::before { content:'(' counter(b) ')'; counter-increment:b; }
.katex .mtr-glue { width:50%; }
.katex .cd-vert-arrow { display:inline-block; position:relative; }
.katex .cd-label-left { display:inline-block; position:absolute; text-align:left; }
.katex .cd-label-right { display:inline-block; position:absolute; text-align:right; }
.katex-display { display:block; margin:em 0; text-align:center; }
.katex-display > .katex { display:block; text-align:center; white-space:nowrap; }
.katex-display > .katex > .katex-html { display:block; position:relative; }
.katex-display > .katex > .katex-html > .tag { position:absolute; right:0; }
.katex-display.leqno > .katex > .katex-html > .tag { left:0; right:auto; }
.katex-display.fleqn > .katex { padding-left:2em; text-align:left; }
body { counter-reset:a b; }
.prism *, .token.pre.gfm * { font-weight:inherit; }
.prism .token.cdata, .prism .token.comment, .prism .token.doctype, .prism .token.prolog, .token.pre.gfm .token.cdata, .token.pre.gfm .token.comment, .token.pre.gfm .token.doctype, .token.pre.gfm .token.prolog { color:slategray; }
.prism .token.punctuation, .token.pre.gfm .token.punctuation { color:rgb(153, 153, 153); }
.prism .namespace, .token.pre.gfm .namespace { opacity:0.7; }
.prism .token.boolean, .prism .token.constant, .prism .token.deleted, .prism .token.number, .prism .token.property, .prism .token.symbol, .prism .token.tag, .token.pre.gfm .token.boolean, .token.pre.gfm .token.constant, .token.pre.gfm .token.deleted, .token.pre.gfm .token.number, .token.pre.gfm .token.property, .token.pre.gfm .token.symbol, .token.pre.gfm .token.tag { color:rgb(153, 0, 85); }
.prism .token.attr-name, .prism .token.builtin, .prism .token.char, .prism .token.inserted, .prism .token.selector, .prism .token.string, .token.pre.gfm .token.attr-name, .token.pre.gfm .token.builtin, .token.pre.gfm .token.char, .token.pre.gfm .token.inserted, .token.pre.gfm .token.selector, .token.pre.gfm .token.string { color:rgb(102, 153, 0); }
.prism .language-css .token.string, .prism .style .token.string, .prism .token.entity, .prism .token.operator, .prism .token.url, .token.pre.gfm .language-css .token.string, .token.pre.gfm .style .token.string, .token.pre.gfm .token.entity, .token.pre.gfm .token.operator, .token.pre.gfm .token.url { color:rgb(166, 127, 89); }
.prism .token.atrule, .prism .token.attr-value, .prism .token.keyword, .token.pre.gfm .token.atrule, .token.pre.gfm .token.attr-value, .token.pre.gfm .token.keyword { color:rgb(0, 119, 170); }
.prism .token.function, .token.pre.gfm .token.function { color:rgb(221, 74, 104); }
.prism .token.important, .prism .token.regex, .prism .token.variable, .token.pre.gfm .token.important, .token.pre.gfm .token.regex, .token.pre.gfm .token.variable { color:rgb(238, 153, 0); }
.prism .token.bold, .prism .token.important, .token.pre.gfm .token.bold, .token.pre.gfm .token.important { font-weight:500; }
.prism .token.italic, .token.pre.gfm .token.italic { font-style:italic; }
html { line-height:1.15; }
body { margin:0; }
article, aside, footer, header, nav, section { display:block; }
h1 { font-size:2em; margin:0.67em 0; }
figcaption, figure { display:block; }
figure { margin:em 40px; }
hr { height:0; overflow:visible; }
main { display:block; }
pre { font:em monospace, monospace; }
a { background:transparent; }
abbr[title] { border-bottom:none; text-decoration:underline; }
b, strong { font-weight:bolder; }
code, kbd, samp { font:em monospace, monospace; }
dfn { font-style:italic; }
mark { background:yellow; color:black; }
small { font-size:80%; }
sub, sup { font-size:75%; line-height:0; position:relative; vertical-align:baseline; }
sub { bottom:-0.25em; }
sup { top:-0.5em; }
audio, video { display:inline-block; }
audio:not([controls]) { display:none; height:0; }
img { border:none; }
svg:not(:root) { overflow:hidden; }
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea { font:100%/1.15 sans-serif; margin:0; }
button { overflow:visible; }
button, select { text-transform:none; }
[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner, [type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner, [type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner, button::-moz-focus-inner { border:none; padding:0; }
[type=button]:-moz-focusring, [type=reset]:-moz-focusring, [type=submit]:-moz-focusring, button:-moz-focusring { outline:buttontext dotted 1px; }
input { overflow:visible; }
[type=checkbox], [type=radio] { padding:0; }
[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, [type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { height:auto; }
::-webkit-file-upload-button { font:inherit; }
fieldset { padding:0.35em 0.75em 0.625em; }
legend { color:inherit; display:table; max-width:100%; padding:0; white-space:normal; }
progress { display:inline-block; vertical-align:baseline; }
textarea { overflow:auto; }
details { display:block; }
summary { display:list-item; }
menu { display:block; }
canvas { display:inline-block; }
[hidden], template { display:none; }
body, html { color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); font:16px/1.67 Lato, Helvetica\ Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-variant-ligatures:common-ligatures; }
.app--dark .layout__panel--editor, .app--dark .layout__panel--preview { color:hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75); }
blockquote, dl, ol, p, pre, ul { margin:1.2em 0; }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { line-height:1.33; margin:1.8em 0; }
h1::after, h2::after { border-bottom:1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0.33); content:''; display:block; position:relative; top:0.33em; }
ol ol, ol ul, ul ol, ul ul { margin:0; }
dt { font-weight:700; }
a { color:rgb(12, 147, 228); text-decoration:underline; }
a:focus, a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
code, pre, samp { font:0.85em Roboto\ Mono, Lucida\ Sans\ Typewriter, Lucida\ Console, monaco, Courrier, monospace; }
code *, pre *, samp * { font-size:inherit; }
blockquote { border-left:5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); padding-left:1.5em; }
.app--dark .layout__panel--editor blockquote, .app--dark .layout__panel--preview blockquote { border-left:hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1); color:hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.4); }
code { background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); padding:2px 4px; }
hr { border-top:solid hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0.33); border-width:1px 0 0; margin:2em 0; }
pre > code { background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); display:block; padding:0.5em; white-space:pre; }
.toc ul { list-style:none; padding-left:20px; }
table { background:transparent; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; }
td, th { border-right:1px solid gainsboro; padding:8px 12px; }
td:last-child, th:last-child { border-right:0; }
td { border-top:1px solid gainsboro; }
mark { background:rgb(248, 248, 64); }
kbd { background:white; border:1px solid rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.25); color:rgb(51, 51, 51); display:inline-block; font:0.8em Lato, Helvetica\ Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0 0.1em; padding:0.1em 0.6em; white-space:nowrap; }
abbr[title] { border-bottom:1px dotted rgb(119, 119, 119); cursor:help; }
img { max-width:100%; }
.task-list-item { list-style:none; }
.task-list-item-checkbox { margin:0 0.2em 0 -1.3em; }
.footnote { font-size:0.8em; position:relative; top:-0.25em; vertical-align:top; }
.page-break-after { page-break-after:always; }
.stackedit__html { margin-bottom:180px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; max-width:750px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; }
.stackedit__toc ul { padding:0; }
.stackedit__toc ul a { margin:0.5rem 0; padding:0.5rem 1rem; }
.stackedit__toc ul ul { color:rgb(136, 136, 136); font-size:0.9em; }
.stackedit__toc ul ul a { margin:0; padding:0.1rem 1rem; }
.stackedit__toc li { display:block; }
.stackedit__toc a { color:inherit; display:block; text-decoration:none; }
.stackedit__toc a:active, .stackedit__toc a:focus, .stackedit__toc a:hover { background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08); }
.stackedit__left { display:none; height:100%; left:0; position:fixed; top:0; width:250px; }
@media (min-width:1060px) { .stackedit__left { display:block; } }
.stackedit__right { left:0; position:absolute; right:0; top:0; }
@media (min-width:1060px) { .stackedit__right { left:250px; } }
.stackedit--pdf blockquote { border-left:rgb(236, 236, 236); }
.stackedit--pdf .stackedit__html { max-width:none; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; }
@font-face { font-family:KaTeX_Script; font-weight:400; src:url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Script-Regular.af7bc98.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Script-Regular.4edf4e0.woff') format('woff'), url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Script-Regular.082640c.ttf') format('truetype'); }
@font-face { font-family:KaTeX_Size1; font-weight:400; src:url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size1-Regular.10ec8be.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size1-Regular.35b9977.woff') format('woff'), url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size1-Regular.2c2dc3b.ttf') format('truetype'); }
@font-face { font-family:KaTeX_Size2; font-weight:400; src:url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size2-Regular.96a09bf.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size2-Regular.9932a08.woff') format('woff'), url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size2-Regular.114ad19.ttf') format('truetype'); }
@font-face { font-family:KaTeX_Size3; font-weight:400; src:url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size3-Regular.2c2f0ef.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size3-Regular.2afba15.woff') format('woff'), url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size3-Regular.a287c06.ttf') format('truetype'); }
@font-face { font-family:KaTeX_Size4; font-weight:400; src:url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size4-Regular.d5822f1.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size4-Regular.f961545.woff') format('woff'), url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Size4-Regular.70174da.ttf') format('truetype'); }
@font-face { font-family:KaTeX_Typewriter; font-weight:400; src:url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Typewriter-Regular.641339e.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Typewriter-Regular.53dcf86.woff') format('woff'), url('/static/fonts/KaTeX_Typewriter-Regular.35fe2cc.ttf') format('truetype'); }
@font-face { font-family:Lato; font-weight:400; src:url('/static/fonts/lato-normal.27bd77b.woff') format('woff'); }
@font-face { font-family:Lato; font-style:italic; font-weight:400; src:url('/static/fonts/lato-normal-italic.f28f2d6.woff') format('woff'); }
@font-face { font-family:Lato; font-weight:600; src:url('/static/fonts/lato-black.f80bda6.woff') format('woff'); }
@font-face { font-family:Lato; font-style:italic; font-weight:600; src:url('/static/fonts/lato-black-italic.798eafd.woff') format('woff'); }
@font-face { font-family:Roboto\ Mono; font-weight:400; src:url('/static/fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.0b6a547.woff') format('woff'); }
@font-face { font-family:Roboto\ Mono; font-weight:600; src:url('/static/fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.819f3b2.woff') format('woff'); }

[last ~30 lines dropped due to StackExchange size limitations]
```